# Clicking a Button, increasing the number in the title

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, int

I'm new to Objective C, and am trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.  Here's what I want to do:

ButtonA1 starts with a random number from 0-4.  I did that with the following code:

```
int intA1 = arc4random() % 5;
NSString *A1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", intA1];
[ButtonA1 setTitle:A1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This works quite nicely.

I then want to be able to click ButtonA1, and have it take the number in the button title, and increment it by one.  The code I came up to pull the number in the button title isn't working.

```
- (IBAction)pushButtonA1:(id)sender {
int buttonCount = [ButtonA1.titleLabel intValue];
}
```

It gives me an error that "No visible @interface for 'UILabel' declares the selector 'intValue'"

Any thoughts on what I should be doing?

Comment: Your problem could easily be solved merely by reading the documentation.

Answer (score 2):

```
int buttonCount = [ButtonA1.titleLabel.text intValue];
```

You need to access the `text` property of the label (you cannot call `intValue` on a `UILabel`).